# Fedora 23 KVM and VLAN tagging

Tags: networking, fedora, vlan

I have a server with a single physical NIC which runs the host as well as one KVM based Linux VM. I need to figure out how to configure the following on the host system:

- The host needs an interface with an IP on VLAN 1
- The VM needs two virtual interfaces, one on VLAN 2 and another one which accepts traffic on all other VLANs.

It's easy to create two virtual interfaces for VLANs 1,2. However, the problem is how to give this virtual "trunk" interface to the VM without also swallowing the packets destined for VLANs 1,2. An easy solution would be to just buy another physical NIC and attach it to a trunk port on the switch and hand it over to the VM. However, is this doable without getting another physical NIC by using the firewall to redirect traffic to VLANs 1,2 out of the virtual trunk port?

Summary of wanted interfaces given one physical interface eth0:

vnic1 - traffic on VLAN 1 (VLAN tags stripped)

vnic2 - traffic on VLAN 2 (VLAN tags stripped)

vnic3 - traffic on all other VLANs (VLAN tags NOT stripped)

(I'm trying to avoid having to get two 35 ft network cables to the switch)